# Python program not working when run in Task Scheduler if Outlook is open

Tags: python, windows, outlook

I have a script that downloads a CSV from Outlook, does some things in Excel, and then sends an email out to people.

When I run it manually with Outlook open, it runs perfectly. But when I try to run it with Task Scheduler, I get this error

"com_error(-2146959355, 'Server execution failed', None, None)"

If I close Outlook and run it using Task Scheduler, it works.

My issue is that I want to run this during the workday so I don't have to remember to send it. During the workday, I always have Outlook open.

Does anyone know how to get it so that the scheduled task can run during the day with Outlook open? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is it possible that there is a mismatch in security contexts? Try running the script "as administrator"

Comment: I'm already running it with highest privileges in Task Scheduler. It runs when I run it in the command prompt

Comment: I opened Outlook as administrator and it worked with Task Scheduler, thanks for the idea!

Comment: I'm glad that worked! Please very the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that there is a mismatch in security contexts? Try running the script or Outlook (or both) "as administrator."

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that the Task Scheduler is using a service account to run the routine. This scenario is not supported when you automate Office applications. Here is what MS states:

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

> If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) article.

If you are dealing with Exchange profiles you may consider using Exchange Web Services for getting the job done. See [Explore the EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/explore-the-ews-managed-api-ews-and-web-services-in-exchange) for more information.